# Updating app won't replace files in .\assets\internal

Tags: android, delphi

Storing application files in a folder, .\assets\internal\MyFilesFolder.

Problems occur when I need to update the app e.g. in Google Play Store.

The files are not replaced. So the updated version uses old files from the first installment.

Is there a way to force an update or a better place to store the files?

(Same problems on IOS)

Thanks

Comment: It seems that Delphi itself have control over the assets update via System.StartUpCopy.pas. Explains same problems with IOS. So a solution might be deleting files before the StartUpCopy is initialized.

Comment: You can also edit the StartupCopy.pas to make it do what you want it to do.